# Half-Precision (2 byte) cast to Float in Python

Tags: python, casting

I'm trying to read a binary file that consists of 2 byte floats, but I cant seem to get the values I want. struct.unpack seems to only work for 4 byte floats and I'm not sure what else is available other than doing the cast completely manually. Is there any way to do this? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Ah, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: Native size and alignment are determined using the C compiler’s `sizeof` expression. This is always combined with native byte order. So I don't see you being able to do this with the current struct module, unless you extend it to include support for Half-Precision floats.

Comment: Well I know that it can be done with numpy for entire files with:
data = np.fromfile(f, dtype='uint16')
data = self.data.reshape((len(self.channel_names),-1),order='F').astype('float')

But this only works for entire files....

Comment: @MartijnPieters: to be clear "padding them out with `\x0` bytes" won't work.  The links that you've provided explain why. It is misleading that your answer also uses "pad them out to 4-byte single-precision float".

Comment: related: in reverse, [Convert Python float to IEEE 754-2008 (binary16) format](https://gist.github.com/zed/59a413ae2ed4141d2037).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: yeah, padding out with nulls is indeed not a viable option; removed the comment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've already got most of the way with `numpy.fromfile`.  Instead use `numpy.frombuffer`:

```
>>> np.frombuffer(buffer("\0\0"), dtype=np.float16)[0]
0.0
>>> np.frombuffer(buffer("\x00\x3c"), dtype=np.float16)[0]
1.0
```

If the data has a known form you can parse out structs by creating a dtype with the appropriate layout.

Comment: it works without the `buffer()`: `np.frombuffer(b'\x00\x3c', dtype='<f2')[0]`

Answer (score 2):

You could pad them out to 4-byte single-precision floats; there are a few people who already have done the gruntwork for you:

- http://forums.devshed.com/python-programming-11/converting-half-precision-floating-point-numbers-from-hexidecimal-to-decimal-576842.html
- http://davidejones.com/blog/1413-python-precision-floating-point/
- http://fpmurphy.blogspot.no/2008/12/half-precision-floating-point-format_14.html

They all parse out the format into it's constituents as documented on the [Wikipedia article on the format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format), padding out the 2 bytes to a 4 bytes single-precision float, then feed that back to the python struct module for converting that to a python float.